# What is meant by abstract="true" in spring?

Tags: java, spring, exception, jakarta-ee

Abstract classes cannot be instantiated in java. But spring says something like bean creation with `abstract="true"`. If a state of an abstract class is initialised only by its child class instance(i guess i am right), then if i need to use that attribute inside the method which is defined in the abstract class then... is there a possibility for it? I have a set of code as follows:

```
class abstract A { 
    private Something somethingObj; 
    // getters and setters are present.

    public void logSomething() { 
        try{ 
           //some code which throws exception 
        }
        catch(Exception e){ 
            somethingObj.logIt(e);// I have some logic inlogIt method. 
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Abstract beans in Spring are somewhat different from abstract classes. In fact, abstract bean in Spring doesn't even have to be mapped to any class. Take this as an example:

```
<bean id="dao" abstract="true">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="someHelper" ref="someHelper"/>
</bean>

<bean id="fooDao" class="FooDao" parent="dao">
    <property name="fooHelper" ref="fooHelper"/>
</bean>
<bean id="barDao" class="BarDao" parent="dao">
    <property name="barHelper" ref="barHelper"/>
</bean>
```

And classes:

```
public class FooDao {
    private DataSource dataSource;
    private SomeHelper someHelper;
    private FooHelper fooHelper;

    //setters
}

public class BarDao {
    private DataSource dataSource;
    private SomeHelper someHelper;
    private BarHelper barHelper;

    //setters
}
```

Note that `FooDao` and `BarDao` do not have any parent (abstract or not) base class in common. Parent abstract bean definition is used only to **group common properties**, so you avoid repetition in XML.

On the other hand introducing abstract `Dao` class that both `FooDao` and `BarDao` inherit from would be a good idea:

```
public abstract Dao {
    protected DataSource dataSource;
    protected SomeHelper someHelper;

    //setters
}

public class FooDao extends Dao {
    private FooHelper fooHelper;

    //setters
}

public class BarDao extends Dao {
    private BarHelper barHelper;

    //setters
}
```

But still `dao` bean doesn't have to define a class. Treat abstract beans as a way to reduce duplication in XML when several concrete beans have same dependencies.

Comment: it should be noted that abstract beans are not instanciated by Spring

Comment: In annotation based bean configuration how to set abstract="true" ?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, abstract parent bean is not necessary to define class attribute, you may just need a common property for sharing.

According to this [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_bean_definition_inheritance.htm)

> The parent bean cannot be instantiated on its own because it is
>   incomplete, and it is also explicitly marked as abstract. When a
>   definition is abstract like this, it is usable only as a pure template
>   bean definition that serves as a parent definition for child
>   definitions.