# How to simplify adding multiple beans in the xml file which uses the DataSource in Spring

Tags: java, spring, jdbc

Im using Spring 3.0 and JDBC I'm currently experimenting with spring for a desktop application.  Each time a class would need to use the datasource declared on my spring_bean_file.xml I would need to declare each of them in the xml file and again initialize each of them in my class.
Below is my xml file

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">       
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
        <property name="url" value="#{T(java.lang.System).getenv(DB_URL')}"/>
        <property name="username" value="#{T(java.lang.System).getenv('DB_USER')}"/>
        <property name="password" value="#{T(java.lang.System).getenv('DB_PASS')}"/>        
    </bean>


<bean id="classA" class="com.example.ClassA">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>

<bean id="classB" class="com.example.ClassB">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

This is my java code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {        

        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring_bean_file.xml");
            ClassA classA = (ClassA) context.getBean("classA");
            ClassB classB = (ClassB) context.getBean("classB");
            try {
                rrRpi.generateRrRpi();
                rrSpi.generateRrSpi();
            } catch (SQLException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

         //close the context             
        ((ClassPathXmlApplicationContext) context).close(); 

    }
```

Id like to know if theres a more efficient way of doing this.  Whats the best approach so I wouldnt need to add a bean for each class that would use the DataSoruce.  Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? You can declare bean template using abstract="true" and use parent="myBean" to add common fields declaration to each bean.

Comment: I dont want to initialize each beans into my class for every class that would need the dataSource e.g. 

ClassA classA = (ClassA) context.getBean("classA"); ClassB classB = (ClassB) context.getBean("classB");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

## Annotations and CLASSPATH scanning

```
@Service
public class ClassA {
    @Resource
    private DataSource dataSource;

    //...
}

@Service
public class ClassB {
    @Resource
    private DataSource dataSource;

    //...
}
```

`dataSource` definition is still required to be in the XML, you also need to replace `classA` and `classB` `<bean/>` definitions with simple:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.example" />

    <!-- ... -->
</beans
```

## @Configuration

Or you can take advantage of very new but exciting Java configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class Cfg {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
        ds.setDriverClassName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver);
        //...
        return ds;
    }

    @Bean
    public ClassA classA() {
        ClassA ca = new ClassA()
        ca.setDataSource(dataSource());
        return ca;
    }

    @Bean
    public ClassB classB() {
        ClassB cb = new ClassB()
        cb.setDataSource(dataSource());
        return cb;
    }

}
```

The benefit of this approach is that you don't need XML, at all:

```
new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Cfg.class);
```

## See also

- [What is meant by abstract="true" in spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9397532) - on how to avoid declaring duplicated dependencies (`dataSource` is actually used as an example).

Comment: can i declare more than one <context:component-scan base-package="com.example" />  just in case the classes are from different packages?

Comment: I tried the service /  resource approach but it says 

the prefix "context" for the element "context:component-scan" is not bound.

Comment: @royjavelosa: you need to define XML schema namespaces, see my updated answer near `context:component-scan`.

Comment: @royjavelosa: looks fine, remeber about XML namespace declaration and to provide real package name.

Comment: I apologize for the code format but should I do it like this?

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">       
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
        <property name="url" value="#{T(java.lang.System).getenv(DB_URL')}"/>
        <property name="username" value="#{T(java.lang.System).getenv('DB_USER')}"/>
        <property name="password" value="#{T(java.lang.System).getenv('DB_PASS')}"/>        
    </bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.example" />
</beans>

Comment: @royjavelosa: yes you already posted the same code, it is correct, but remember about package name and XML namespace.

Comment: Thanks! Just one more thing if its ok. For desktop application how do I reference the .xml file I usually use the code below but since im already using the context:component approach whats the best way to reference the ApplicationContext.xml 'ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("ApplicationContext.xml");' 'ClassA classA = (ClassA) context.getBean("classA");'

I do this on the main method.

Comment: @royjavelosa: `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` is fine in desktop application. Unfortunately you have to reference the very first bean somehow. Your method is OK, but consider strongly typed version: `ClassA classA = context.getBean(ClassA.class)` (no downcasting)

Comment: Thanks alot!  using classA = context.getBean(ClassA.class) syntax saved me from the redundancy of using context.getBean("classA") context.getBean("classB") etc. as long as I put all the related beans on a single application context.  Spring is indeed very powerful and flexible. :)